# No sent mail in password change django

Tags: django, passwords

I'm using django to create an app for clients.
And i have a little problem with the password auth view in django.

I have 2 specifics account, the 'pros' and the 'patients', they can both login, logout, and create their account.

I used the django auth to allow pros to change their password, and it works, the pro receive the email with the link and can change his forgotten password. I did the same with patient but the email is not send.

This is my code :

```
    # RESET PRO
url(
    r'^mdp-lost-pro/$',
    auth_views.password_reset,
    {
        'template_name': 'pro/login/mdp-lost.html',
        'html_email_template_name': 'emails/password_reset_email_pro.html',
        'post_reset_redirect': 'password_reset_done',
    },
    name='password_reset_pro'
),
url(
    r'^mdp-lost-pro-ok/$',
    auth_views.password_reset_done,
    {'template_name': 'pro/login/mdp-lost-ok.html'},
    name='password_reset_done'
),
url(
    r'^mdp-reset-pro/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
    auth_views.password_reset_confirm,
    {
        'template_name': 'pro/login/mdp-reset-confirm.html',
        'post_reset_redirect': 'password_reset_complete',
    },
    name='password_reset_confirm'
),
url(
    r'^mdp-reset-pro-ok/$',
    auth_views.password_reset_complete,
    {'template_name': 'pro/login/mdp-reset-done.html'},
    name='password_reset_complete'
),

# RESET PATIENT
url(
    r'^mdp-lost-patient/$',
    auth_views.password_reset,
    {
        'template_name': 'patient/login/mdp-lost.html',
        'html_email_template_name': 'emails/password_reset_email_patient.html',
        'post_reset_redirect': 'password_reset_patient_done',
    },
    name='password_reset_patient'
),
url(
    r'^mdp-lost-patient-ok/$',
    auth_views.password_reset_done,
    {
        'template_name': 'patient/login/mdp-lost-ok.html',
    },
    name='password_reset_patient_done'
),
url(
    r'^mdp-reset-patient/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
    auth_views.password_reset_confirm,
    {
        'template_name': 'patient/login/mdp-reset-confirm.html',
        'post_reset_redirect': 'password_reset_patient_complete',
    },
    name='password_reset_patient_confirm'
),
url(
    r'^mdp-reset-patient-ok/$',
    auth_views.password_reset_complete,
    {'template_name': 'patient/login/mdp-reset-done.html'},
    name='password_reset_patient_complete'
),
```

The fact is that the only things who change between the pros and the patients in this code is the name of the different urls, for pros it's the actual based-name url, and patient not (maybe the problem came from there ?).

Does someone have tips to help me with that or already saw this?

PS : Actually i have 2 type of account, but in long terms the application will have something like 20 or more types accounts possible (pros, patients, specialists, childrens, etc...), they can all create their account, login, logout, and change the forgotten password.

Thanks for your futures answers, and sorry for my bad english ! :)

Comment: Reup, i still have the problem, any suggestions please ?